# Years Lived/trivia Program Issue

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm creating a program that finds the amount of years a person has been alive based off a date they input, and then gives them trivia for the decade they were alive in. However, when I run it, I get an error saying that the input date cannot be converted into Doubles. I'm very new to this, so any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("When were you born? Expressed dd/mm/yyyy, please.")

        Dim firstDate, msg As String
        Dim secondDate As Date
        firstDate = Console.ReadLine()

        Try
            secondDate = CDate(firstDate)
            msg = "Years from today (Rounded up, of course!): " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, Now, secondDate)
            Console.WriteLine(msg)
        Catch
            Console.WriteLine("That's not how I asked you to write the date!")
        End Try

        If firstDate < 1900 Then
            Console.WriteLine("...How are you even alive? Nice job!")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1900 And firstDate < 1910 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You're pretty old. You've seen a few world wars and the Russian Revolution--that's pretty sweet! Your age, I mean, not so much the wars...")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1910 And firstDate < 1920 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You probably grew up in the Roaring Twenties--Gatsby? What Gatsby?")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1920 And firstDate < 1930 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Well you likely missed the whole Roaring Twenties thing for learning to walk, but hey, at least you got the Great Depression! Oh...")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1930 And firstDate < 1940 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Looks like you were just young see the Second World War. And if you weren't lucky, fight in it.")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1940 And firstDate < 1950 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You were born in the same decade as Bruce Lee. 'Nuff said.")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1950 And firstDate < 1960 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You're from the same age as Bill Murray and Jay Leno.")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1960 And firstDate < 1970 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You're about the same age as my parents. How does that make you feel?")
        ElseIf firstDate = 1969 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Nice.")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1970 And firstDate < 1980 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You were a teenager when the Challenger space shuttle exploded.")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1980 And firstDate < 1990 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You grew up in the Eighties. I'm so sorry.")
        ElseIf firstDate > 1990 And firstDate < 2000 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Say 'Ninties Kids!' again! I dare you!")
        ElseIf firstDate > 2000 And firstDate < 2010 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Aren't you a little young for this sort of thing?")
        ElseIf firstDate > 2010 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Either your parents are doing this for you, or you're FROM THE FUTURE!!! Please be the latter.")
        End If

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Please do not specify language in title, tags serves this purpose better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change every

```
firstDate < n
```

... into this:

```
secondDate.Year < n
```

Do the same for > and = operators too.

I would also advise that you change this line:

```
secondDate = CDate(firstDate)
```

... into this line:

```
secondDate = DateTime.ParseExact(firstDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have done it for the most part.

Comment: What part have you got left?

Comment: Nothing major, just have to add some comments and perhaps more info to the 'trivia' parts.

Comment: Okay. If you are done with this thread please do not forget to mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a date type directly with a numeric type. However, in your case it appears that `secondDate` is just `firstDate` coerced into a `Date` type.

Therefore use `secondDate.Year` in your `If` statements instead.

e.g. `secondDate.Year < 1900`